# How to make after the execution of "switch" - "break" code continued to work?

Tags: c#

**Class `ParserWorker`**
The `WorkerHTMLFile()` method iterates through the list.
The list `ListUrlActive` contains 4 lines.

The `ParsingPage(string source)` method sends the sparse page to the `SiteParser` class.

**Class `SiteParser`**
Method `Parsing(IHtmlDocument document)` after executing `break`, `case "Type_2"` : interrupts the execution of the code.

If I understood correctly, then the execution of the code should return to the `ParserWorker` class, to the `WorkerHTMLFile()` method in the `for` loop.

And take the next line of the "ListUrlActive" list, but this does not happen.
The code processes only the first line and terminates the execution of the code on the `break` `case "Type_2"`

**Question.**
How to make that after performing `break`, `case "Type_2"` the code continues to work further?

```
class ParserWorker
        {
            public void WorkerHTMLFile()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= ListUrlActive.Count; i++)
                {
                    string source = File.ReadAllText(ListUrlActive[i]);                
                    ParsingPage(source);
                }
            }

            public async void ParsingPage(string source)
            {
                var domParser = new HtmlParser();

                IHtmlDocument document = await domParser.ParseAsync(source);

                siteParser.Parsing(document);
            }
        }

        public class SiteParser
        {
            public async void Parsing(IHtmlDocument document)
            {
                switch (objectParsing)
                {
                    case "Type_1":
                        /// ...
                        /// ... Code
                        /// ...

                        break;

                    case "Type_2":                    
                        var domParserAnnounc = new HtmlParser();
                        var htmlBlockAnnounc = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.flexRoot > div.view.main");

                        foreach (var item in htmlBlockAnnounc)
                        {
    string s = item.OuterHtml;
                            IHtmlDocument documentCur = await domParserAnnounc.ParseAsync(s);

                            ParsingPoster(documentCur);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

public async void ParsingPoster(IHtmlDocument document)
        {

            try
            {

             try
                {
                     email = document.QuerySelectorAll("#start_widget > div:nth-child(3) > div.form-line.view-form-line > div.adv-point.view-adv-point > script:nth-child(3)")[0].TextContent.Trim();

                    email = wordProcessing.FindRegularExpression(email, @"(?<=eval\(unescape\(').*(?='\)\))");
                    email = wordProcessing.DecodeResult(email);

                    IHtmlDocument htmlDocumentEmail = await domParser.ParseAsync(email);                 
                    var itemsAttr = htmlDocumentEmail.QuerySelectorAll("a"); 
                    email = itemsAttr[0].TextContent.Trim();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    InfoMessageErrorEvent?.Invoke("Поле: 'email'. Error !!!" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s1 = ex.Message;
                string s2 = ex.StackTrace;
                // throw;
            }


        }
```

**Update_1**
**Class `ParserWorker`**

`WorkerHTMLFile ()` method
It was: `public void WorkerHTMLFile ()`
It became: `public async void WorkerHTMLFile ()`
Changed the composition of the method.

`ParsingPage (string source)` method
It was: `public async void ParsingPage (string source)`
It became: `public async Task <IHtmlDocument> ParsingPage (string source)`
Changed the composition of the method.

**Class `SiteParser`**
Method `Parsing (IHtmlDocument document)`
It was: `public async void Parsing (IHtmlDocument document)`
From: `public async Task Parsing (IHtmlDocument document)`

It was: `ParsingPoster (documentCur);`
Now: `await ParsingPoster (documentCur);`

**Code**

```
class ParserWorker
{
    public async void WorkerHTMLFile()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= ListUrlActive.Count; i++)
        {
            string source = File.ReadAllText(ListUrlActive[i]);                

            IHtmlDocument document = await ParsingPage(source);

            await siteParser.Parsing(document);

        }
    }

    public async Task<IHtmlDocument> ParsingPage(string source)
    {
        IHtmlDocument document = null;
        try
        {
            var domParser = new HtmlParser();

            IHtmlDocument document = await domParser.ParseAsync(source);

            document = await siteParser.Parsing(document);      
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                string s = ex.Message;
                string s1 = ex.StackTrace;
                // throw;
        }
        return document;
    }
}

public class SiteParser
{
    public async Task Parsing(IHtmlDocument document)
    {
        switch (settingOper.objectParsing)
        {
            case "Type_1":
                /// ...
                /// ... Code
                /// ...

                break;

            case "Type_2":                    
                var domParserAnnounc = new HtmlParser();
                var htmlBlockAnnounc = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.flexRoot > div.view.main");

                foreach (var item in htmlBlockAnnounc)
                {
                    string s = item.OuterHtml;
                    IHtmlDocument documentCur = await domParserAnnounc.ParseAsync(s);

                    await ParsingPoster(documentCur);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

public async void ParsingPoster(IHtmlDocument document)
        {

            try
            {

             try
                {
                     email = document.QuerySelectorAll("#start_widget > div:nth-child(3) > div.form-line.view-form-line > div.adv-point.view-adv-point > script:nth-child(3)")[0].TextContent.Trim();

                    email = wordProcessing.FindRegularExpression(email, @"(?<=eval\(unescape\(').*(?='\)\))");
                    email = wordProcessing.DecodeResult(email);

                    IHtmlDocument htmlDocumentEmail = await domParser.ParseAsync(email);                 
                    var itemsAttr = htmlDocumentEmail.QuerySelectorAll("a"); 
                    email = itemsAttr[0].TextContent.Trim();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    InfoMessageErrorEvent?.Invoke("Поле: 'email'. Error !!!" + ex.Message);
                }

                //...
                // ... Parsing additional fields ...
                //...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s1 = ex.Message;
                string s2 = ex.StackTrace;
                // throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to remove Async from ParsingPage and Parsing methods.

Comment: `async void` is for EventHandlers. Use `async Task` instead. Then it is awaitable. Also, [do not mix sync and async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: My question is, why using `switch statement` if you want to continue the process below?

Comment: @VijunavVastivch 


I do not quite understand your question.
I used `switch` to change the direction of the code depending on the condition (" Type_1 "or" Type_2 ").
I thought the code should continue to work after `switch`.
Or are there other ways to solve my problem?

Sorry if my question is not correct, I only learn to program

Comment: @Fildor 
`async task` applied. Does not help.
Problem still exists.
The link that you suggested was studied, but I do not understand how to apply it for my case.
Could you show in more detail how to do this?

Comment: @Gaurav I deleted `Async`. That helped.
But I would like to leave `Async`.
How to make the code work with `Async`?

Comment: @eusataf can you please show me the code for ParsingPoster?

Comment: @Gaurav 
Updated question

Comment: Switch statements work on a case by case basis, now if you want a certain action to be performed on 2 specific cases you can `case "type_1", "type_2": ...` but it cannot execute the next case if the value of `ettingOper.objectParsing` is still on for example `type_1`, it will never execute `type_2` in the same process unless `Parsing` executes again.

Comment: I think you are mistaken what the async keyword does. A common misconception is that it makes your function execute asynchronously (concurrently) if you put it there. It doesn't. It is just an implementation detail that allows you to use "await" in the function that is marked with it. So since there are no awaits in that code, my suspicion is that it will in fact execute synchronously.

Comment: @Fildor I made the code work.
Could you have a look.
Maybe you have comments, offers?
Or all the same, the code will still run synchronously?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the updated code which can help you :

```
class ParserWorker
{
    public void WorkerHTMLFile()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= ListUrlActive.Count; i++)
        {
            string source = File.ReadAllText(ListUrlActive[i]);
            ParsingPage(source);
        }
    }

    public async void ParsingPage(string source)
    {
        var domParser = new HtmlParser();

        IHtmlDocument document = await domParser.ParseAsync(source);

        siteParser.Parsing(document);
    }
}

public class SiteParser
{
    public async void Parsing(IHtmlDocument document)
    {
        switch (settingOper.objectParsing)
        {
            case "Type_1":
                /// ...
                /// ... Code
                /// ...

                break;

            case "Type_2":
                var domParserAnnounc = new HtmlParser();
                var htmlBlockAnnounc = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.flexRoot > div.view.main");

                foreach (var item in htmlBlockAnnounc)
                {
                    string s = item.OuterHtml;
                    IHtmlDocument documentCur = await domParserAnnounc.ParseAsync(s);

                    await ParsingPoster(documentCur);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

public async void ParsingPoster(IHtmlDocument document)
{

    try
    {

        try
        {
            settingOper.email = document.QuerySelectorAll("#start_widget > div:nth-child(3) > div.form-line.view-form-line > div.adv-point.view-adv-point > script:nth-child(3)")[0].TextContent.Trim();

            if (settingOper.email == null)
            {
                settingOper.email = document.QuerySelectorAll("div[class='adv-point view-adv-point']>script[type*='text/javascript']")[0].TextContent.Trim();
            }
            settingOper.email = wordProcessing.FindRegularExpression(settingOper.email, @"(?<=eval\(unescape\(').*(?='\)\))");
            settingOper.email = wordProcessing.DecodeResult(settingOper.email);

            IHtmlDocument htmlDocumentEmail = await domParser.ParseAsync(settingOper.email);
            var itemsAttr = htmlDocumentEmail.QuerySelectorAll("a");
            settingOper.email = itemsAttr[0].TextContent.Trim();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            InfoMessageErrorEvent?.Invoke("Поле: 'email'. Error !!!" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s1 = ex.Message;
        string s2 = ex.StackTrace;
        // throw;
    }


}
```

I majorly fixed the async and await issue for you at some places.

Comment: Rather than just pasting updated code you should also try to explain what you changed and why. As it is for this answer to actually explain anything you need to diff your code with the original to find where you have made changes...

Comment: @Gaurav  
Did you change just that: `await ParsingPoster(documentCur);`?

Comment: Yes I think on rest of the places it was already present. Did it work for you?

Comment: @eusataf you need to debug your code and find out the point of issue then only we can help.